# preview-latex with LuaLaTeX

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

I'm trying to configure AUCTeX for LuaLaTeX, and compiling works fine with this additions in my `.emacs`:

```
(defun my-latex ()
  "Latex mode customizations"
  (auto-fill-mode t)
  (reftex-mode t)
  (TeX-engine-set "luatex")
  (setq TeX-electric-math (cons "$" "$") ) ; auto close dollars
  (setq TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript t) ; use _{} instead of _
  (setq font-latex-fontify-script 'multi-level) ; 2^2^2 as multiple scripts
  ;; Use zathura for previews
  (setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
  (setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Zathura"))
  ;; Hide some boilerplate
  (TeX-fold-mode 1)
  ;; Big faces for sections, chapters, etc.
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-sectioning-1-face nil
                      :foreground "#ffcc66" :height 1.5 :bold t)
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-sectioning-2-face nil
                      :foreground "#ffcc66" :height 1.2 :bold t)
  (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-sectioning-3-face nil
                      :foreground "#ffcc66" :height 1.2 :bold nil)
  )
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex)
```

But if I use `preview-latex` with `C-c C-p C-s`, it fails with `error in process sentinel: Opening input file: No such file or directory, /tmp/_region_.prv/tmp20357KF2/preview.ps`. The file that I'm trying to preview is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{equation}
f = b^{4}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What should I change in my `.emacs` to make `latex-preview` work? Ideally, with Unicode input.

Comment: Does loading the package `luatex85` help?  It does for me.

Comment: @giordano Totally! Works like a charm! If you want, please do a full answer so I can assign you the bounty.

Comment: Good, but I'll first ask to @ArashEsbati if he wants to answer the question, because this is a trick of his ;-)

Comment: @giordano - Thanks for the offer, but go ahead for the bounty `:-)` Please mention that this issue is hopefully fixed with current `preview` on CTAN and texlive2017 or AUCTeX release 11.90.3.

Comment: @ArashEsbati do you want to expand the answer better explaining the origin of the issue? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

There are incompatibilities between recent LuaTeX versions and the `preview` LaTeX package, but they can be fixed by loading the [`luatex85`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luatex85) package in your document.

Note however that this issue [has been already fixed](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=cf6480c52138e989d18734f61395bc61e0178932) in upstream version of `preview`: the `preview` package load itself `luatex85`, if present, so that you don't have to do it manually in your documents.  This fix will be available in TeX Live 2017 and the ELPA release of AUCTeX 11.90.3.

### Background

Since LuaTeX started as a descendant of pdfTeX, it used the names of extended primitives provided by pdfTeX.  `preview` supported LuaTeX out of the box as its detection mechanism for pdfTeX worked also for LuaTeX.  Things changed with the advent of LuaTeX 0.85 where almost all the pdfTeX extended primitves with names `\pdf...` were renamed or removed.

LaTeX3 project provides a compatibility package `luatex85` which redirects old pdfTeX primitives to new LuaTeX counterparts.